# How do get the result from REST website that returns only text?

Tags: reactjs, rest

I'm trying to use a REST web service from Geonames.org. When I try to manually put in the url with the parameters, it would only return the Country Code. I've tried to search for ways to implement it, but most of what I've seen return JSON text with multiple keys and data. I feel like the answer should be pretty simple, but I'm unsure.

I'm trying to use this for a React project I'm working on.

[Here is an example of what the url returns](http://api.geonames.org/countryCode?formatted=true&lat=47.03&lng=10.2&username=vincea23)

Comment: Add response in your question, we don't know the response type,

Answer (score 0):

Just looked into the docs of that API, and it says if you want to receive `JSON` responses simply add `JSON` keyword to the endpoint. Like here for given endpoint you have:

```
http://api.geonames.org/countryCodeJSON?formatted=true&lat=47.03&lng=10.2&username=demo
```

so just change `countryCode` to `countryCodeJSON`.

Source: http://www.geonames.org/export/JSON-webservices.html